# Django database urls?

Tags: django, database-connection, django-database

I am developing a **Django** app but unfortunately my laptop is broken and will take a month to get repaired. So mean while I am using a android app called Termux to work on the project. But Termux still doesn't have a postgresql package and don't want to mess my settings just for running the project. So how can I use dj_database_url packages to configure my databases using database urls??

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using the **dj_database_url** module.

After installing the module in the project,  then this config needs to be done(example for default database):
`db_from_env=dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500) 
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)`

Now export a environment variable named DATABASE_URL for the database server

More info here: https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url/blob/master/README.rst